# How to upload new APK to Android Beta using Fastlane?

Tags: android, cordova, apk, fastlane

I have an APK running in production on Google Play (`Version` 0.0.15, `Version Code` 158) and I plan to upload a new APK to the Beta track (for the moment, I haven't set any APK on Beta track yet). I want to manage it with Fastlane.

Here's my `config.xml` file sample :

```
<widget id="xxx.xxx.xxx" version="0.0.16" versionCode="159" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
```

I believe that `cordova build android --release` is what I want to generate the appropriate APK. After having signed it and zipped it, I run `fastlane beta` :

> [!] Google Api Error: multiApkShadowedActiveApk: Version 16 of this app can not be downloaded by any devices as they will all receive APKs with higher version codes.

This is my fastlane track in `Fastfile` :

```
desc "Submit a new Beta Build"
  lane :beta do
    supply(
      track: "beta",
      apk: "platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/app.apk"
    )
  end
```

**Am I doing it right ? Is it all about versions and version codes ?**

Answer (score 1):

This is an error returned by Google Play API indicating that the APK that is in Production is using a higher versionCode than the APK you are attempting to upload to the Beta Track. For an active APK in Beta, the versionCode of the APK must be higher than the versionCode of an APK in Production. And an APK in Alpha must be higher than both Production and Beta.

P.S. I think you also need to set the package_name variable in the supply command to match the package name of your Google Play app.